# How to get the list of envelopes from a DocuSign account?

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to fetch the list of envelopes from a docusign account. We are calling the list folder API ( https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/list/ )but its returning all folders with itemcount 0. We checked the account and the account admin who has authenticated the account did not have any envelopes, However other users had envelopes. We want to fetch the all envelopes of all users, but are not able to find the api endpoint which helps us get it.

We also have get envelope api which provides the details of single envelope by taking the id of the envelope (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/ ). But to use this api also we will need the ids of all envelopes. Please guide us how we can get the list of all envelopes of all the users from docusign.

We tried the list folder api

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/list/

But this gave all folers with itemcount 0

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, neither of these endpoints is what you want.
The best option for this is this one - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/

I would recommend you look at the code example for this - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/list-envelope-status-changes/

Also, ignore the comment about 6 months, I believe it's not true, it depends on how you call this method, what parameters you pass. If you have a large number of envelopes, you cannot get them all in a single API call.